# Why Would A .NET 4.0 WPF App Have Much Better UI Performance On VMWare Guest Than Host?

Tags: .net, wpf

When testing our C#/.NET4.0/WPF app on a fresh Win 7 Enterprise x64 in a VMWare 7.1.2 Workstation Guest configured with 2 GB RAM, startup time and UI performance was far superior to using the same app in the host (without any VMs running).

The host has 8GB RAM, but is fairly loaded. The test on the host was also performed on the guest with more load on the host, plus the overhead of the VM, still with similar results, the guest being faster and having a smoother UI (I know, a subjective measure).

Here are some possible reasons:

- WPF rendering is superior with the VMWare display system, compared to the (possibly) buggy AMD driver on the physical.  Note that the guest is configured with the "Accelerate 3D Graphics" setting enabled. Graphics card is an ATI/AMD Firepro and I had to rollback from the latest driver as it pretty much murdered WPF performance, both on our app and VS2010.
- Registry and other cruft having a particularly large effect on WPF / .NET perf versus the clean VM.

Can anyone give me any other ideas on why this is the case, since asking customers to use the product in a VMWare guest using a clean OS install would be peculiar.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of asking them to do that, why sweat it?  If it suits the customer's requirements and is "fast enough", then why does it matter if it could go faster?  This is especially true if the customer is a corporate client or an internal team, and you don't have to wow them enough to get direct sales...

Comment: Sorry Merlyn, that last part was somewhat facetious. We have customers complaining about perf issues and the bizarre thing is this scenario is possibly the fastest I've seen it perform - even faster than on physical machines with more exotic hardware. Previous version was C++ so the perf bar was high to start with.

Comment: Merlyn, you misunderstand me, I meant that I was being flippant in my last sentence of the original question, not you. I apologise for any unintended offence. Ishould keep my questions more concise!

Comment: @ari... I have the exact same issue.  Maxed-out hardware but crappy performance compared to the VM.  BUT.. I too have an ATI/AMD and have always hated their drivers so your comments are even more interesting to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some odd registry settings that are hindering the perf of WPF.  WPF uses 3 "tiers" of rendering (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx) and depending on specific settings, you may be getting different perf based on where the original VM was set up.  When you clone a VM, you take with it all Registry settings.  Here are the [ones to check out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx)

Comment: You could scale down these settings to balance visuals with hardware.  My guess is the clean OS uses the best optimization for the hardware it has available.

Comment: Thanks Nate - all default. The logging in the app reports Tier 2 capability and hardware rendering in effect on both the guest and the host.  I'm intimately familiar with those settings.  Also note that the VM is a clean install, not a conversion from the VMWare host. I forced software rendering in the app when running in the VM and it did reduce performance slightly, but still not to the level of the physical host using hardware rendering on a decent graphics card.

Comment: Are they set up for multi-monitor?  "Exceeding the available amount of texture memory will usually cause WPF render logic to fall back to software, and that multiple displays (multi-monitor) have a multiplicative effect on the amount of video memory that is required for an application" Source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx  You can also look into dxdiag if you haven't already.

Comment: I do have multiple monitors and on the physical box, they are usually both at 1920x1200.  The VM certainly only sees 1. I'll investigate this route. Thanks again.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm interested in seeing what happened.

Comment: Hi Nate, the dual monitors at high resolution played a part. What quite possibly was the fix was actually running the "Windows Experience Index" on the host machine.  If you recall, I had installed a new driver, which was bad, then rolled back to the original. Refreshing the WinSAT seemed to make the difference. By the way, some power profiles that mess with the graphics card can also seriously affect WPF performance, it wasn't that in this case, but just for information.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  At least the problem is resolved.  WPF perf can be a bear to diagnose.