# Why does a WPF app in a VM perform better than one running direct in the OS?

Tags: wpf, virtual-machine, windows-7-x64

We have a higher-end Win7-64 Dell precision workstation notebook with an i7, 8 gigs of ram, tons of hd space and running dedicated AMD graphics.  The machine is about a month old.  It was one of the highest-end we could get at the time.

What we're experiencing is when we run our WPF/SQL Server (local) app, it tends to hang and stall, sometimes completely crashing, but mostly just hanging until we force it to close.  However, the exact same installer running in a VMware virtual machine running on that same machine runs flawlessly.  Actually, the VM install runs better than a lot of native installs on other machines.  It's very snappy with no hangs or hesitations at all.  But again, same app, same installer running direct in the OS, and we're back to the issues above.

We've ran all Windows updates.... we've tried completely reinstalling everything... .NET frameworks, SQL Server, video drivers, even updated the BIOS and checked for rogue services but it still happens.

At first we thought it was Symantec AV's real-time protection because when we first shut that off, things started getting snappy again (and slowed down and froze when it auto-re-enabled itself furthering this hypothesis) but then it just started slowing down again, and more surprising, that same AV is running in the VM without issue!  Checked the exceptions but there weren't any.

We even tried forcing WPF to run in software-render mode but again, nothing.

Now the odd thing is this only seems to be happening on this and a few other machines, but we can't seem to find anything in common except they're all running Win7 64-bit.  As such, we have absolutely no idea where to start.  And since most are hangs, not crashes, we can't even look at the crash reports.

So can anyone give us any idea what else we can look at?  This is holding up us shipping a three-years-in-the-making major release of our software so to say this is a show-stopper would be an understatement. We've been stumped for about a month now and getting nowhere fast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000226/ - Could be a dupe.  Sounds quite similar.

Comment: Hanging until force close - have you tried attaching a debugger to it and checking out what code it was running while hung?  [.Net source stepping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx) might be extra helpful for that scenario.  Is there a difference in the number of procs between the VMs and the real machine?

Comment: Damn you and your superior searching skills!  I looked and looked for something similar first and found nothing which is odd considering that title is a litany of keywords that I tried!  :P  I stink at this! LOL

Comment: BTW tried the stepping, but you cant step through a hang.  And the VS debugger is attached too, but it too hangs when this happens.  Really stumped and really a bi*** when you cant see the hang itself.  More CPU cores in the host, but they all go to zero when this happens.

Comment: I cheated.  I had already seen that question and had it in my search history :)  I was wondering if this was the difference between a single proc and multi-proc, because I think you might not get thread deadlocks on a single proc machine.  Also, check that link, there seems to be an accepted answer on it.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am intrigued. Could you please let us know how you solved the problem? Is it beacuse of a UI automation client in the host (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978520)?

Comment: Good thing to know, but alas, we're .NET 4.0 and it explicitly says that doesn't happen with that version.  Still, thanks for the heads-up!  Should help others so I'm voting that up.

Comment: In your shoes I would simply do a lot of trial and error testing.
1) Try win 7 32 -bit; 2) Try different VM-s VirtualBox, Hyper-V, VMWare, Virtual PC etc (use multople CPUs for VM); 3) uninstall all AV; 4) If there is a specific scenario that tends to hang, eg. using a certain function in your app, then start by commenting out the rest of your app code, then continue testing and commenting out code of the function; 5) Insert tracing into your code - write out what your app is doing (this gives clues to as where in your code a hang might happen); 6) remove multi-threading from code;

Comment: All of the above is ment to help pinpoint the issue. The first step is to see if the environment is the cause (OS, drivers, AV, etc). From your problem description, that would be my guess. The next step is to see which part of your code can't handle the environment or causes it to misbehave. Finally, after pinpointing the problem to a certain code area you can start figuring out what is wrong with it...

Comment: Also check/minipulate the compile options.

Comment: @Balam, Not the issue.  See my answer below.  It's a bug in the framework itself.

Comment: @Jimmy, turns out that was more close than I thought.  See my answer below.

Comment: If it's helpful, please vote it up! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!! Turns out there's a bug in .NET 4.0 regarding UI Automation and the changes MS introduced. Here's the info, and the fix! (Note: Even if you call MS, they will send you a link, but it's always a broken link. I managed to track this down manually.)

Note: Their article talks about a specific case that causes this behavior, but if you google around, you'll see tons of issues around hangs related to those DLLs. The latest is they're promising a fix in the .NET 4.5 runtime (from a MS post on this issue.)

Here's the KB article...
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2484841/en-us

...and here is the actual hotfix.
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2484841/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5583

Apparently the VM didn't suffer from this.  We weren't sure if the VM had the hotfix applied or not or if this only happens on non-virtualized machines.  Still, this solved all of the issues and the app is now snappy again.  (Man, was this fun to track down! Ugh!!)

Comment: Both links broke

Comment: Yeah, not sure where they are now, but from what I can tell, the patches these point to have been rolled into the latest versions so I'm not sure these are needed anymore.